# XFPageRendererView error on XAML previewer

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am developing `Xamarin.Forms` on `Visual studio 2015`, I have a mac connected to my PC, when trying to preview by the option 
*(View > OtherWindows >Xamrin.Forms Previewer)* The android preview shows the error below

[image: I am stuck here]

But the IOS preview is working fine and is updated as soon as I change the `xaml` code

How can I fix this ? What I have already tried are

1. Rebuilding the project and solution
2. Installing the latest android build tool
3. Restarting Visual studio
4. Updating Android SDK
5. Installing a `x64` bit `JDK` and mapping its path in visual studio

none of these are working. I would also like to know if `ANDROID NDK` has something to do with this (currently running `android-ndk-r10e`) and if it is necessary to update that as well ?? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue . I re-posted your topic in Xamarin forum . Hope that is ok : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87991/xfpagerendererview-error-on-xaml-previewer/p1?new=1

I'm using ndk r13b - same issue